# What kind of hash/encoding does pfSense use for its IPsec keys?

Tags: encryption, hash, vpn, pfsense

Trying to learn more about strongSwan and IPsec tunnels, I had set up a basic (and local) site-to-site IPsec tunnel between 2 machines running pfSense.

While studying the ipsec.secrets file (/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.secrets), I have noticed that the basic (and not secure!) pre-shared key (PSK) '**vpn**' has been converted to '**0sdnBu**'. Does anyone know what hash this could be? Feels like it could be relevant if I would like to create a tunnel between pfSense and another kind of system running strongSwan.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a Base64-encoding of the PSK. The `0s` prefix indicates this to strongSwan and the rest of the value is parsed as binary value accordingly:

```
$ echo -n 'vpn' | base64
dnBu
$ echo -n 'dnBu' | base64 -d
vpn
```

Similarly, the `0x` prefix would allow passing shared secrets in hex-encoding (e.g. `vpn` would then be `0x76706e`).

pfSense probably encodes the shared secret in Base64 to avoid issues with special characters (or character sets) when users configure this via the Web UI.